# JavaScript's window.location vs form.submit()

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, what is the difference between `window.location` and `form.submit()` *(GET with no parameters)*?

I have seen people using `form.submit()` *(GET method with no parameters)* over `window.location` for just a simple redirection of page. Why? and what are the benefits of that? Is that some kind of hack to achieve something?

AFAIK, `form.submit()` leaves a trailing `?` behind the URL even where there is no parameters and that bugs me a little.

Comment: _"what is the difference between"_ -> Google. _"Why?"_/_"and what are the benefits of that?"_/_"Is that some kind of hack to achieve something?"_ -> Ask the relevant developers. _"leaves a trailing ? ... that bugs me a little."_ -> ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Andreas Have you tried googling about this? I actually did before I posted this question. I couldn't find anything relevant for my context. If you find anything relevant, you are welcome to share the page(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always prefer using `window.location`. Unless you want to need parameters, using `form.submit()` is completely illogical, as it has more overhead. If one just thinks about it, `form.submit()` is a function call, while `window.location` is just changing a variable. Although it is a microscopic performance difference, calling the function will be less efficient than assigning a variable.

Comment: How about redirecting to a page with one known parameter, say, `/page?id=1234` ? Would you hardcode the link to `window.location` or build a form element/object to stuff the parameter in?

Comment: @user2526586 It's really just personal preference. I personally would hardcore it, but using a form object could make your code cleaner. Hard coding it would ideally be better performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If the form doesn't have any parameters, assigning to `window.location` is the equivalent and would be the usual way to do it.

But most forms *do* have parameters. `form.submit()` is a general way to submit the form and get the parameters sent automatically, rather than having to construct the URL in your own code. It will also send a `POST` request if that's the form's method. So it's useful in general purpose libraries.